Azure.AI.OpenAI - GetChatCompletionsStreaming - Send and Receive Multiple Messages In the Same Context
I have a use case that is very simple but is proving quite difficult, I want to create a programmatic application that sends and receives a series of messages in the same context to a GPT model hosted on Azure Open AI, rough sketched this would look something like:
Uri azureOpenAIResourceUri = new Uri(azureOpenAIResourceUriEndpoint);
AzureKeyCredential azureOpenAIApiKeyCredential = new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenAIApiKey);
OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(azureOpenAIResourceUri, azureOpenAIApiKeyCredential);
ChatCompletionsOptions chatCompletionsOptions = GenerateInitialChatCompletionsOptions(AITemplate, customAITemplate, query);

//Send message: "What is 1 + 1"

//Get answer, print to user

//Send message: "Can you add 2 to the previous answer"

//Get answer, print to user

//etc...

Apparently, searching the internet, I've discovered this is a non trivial use case(because I haven't found anyone else doing it), I can do the first part using the following code:
await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(chatCompletionsOptions)

But after I receive the first reply I don't know how to reply to that reply. I don't see a way to obtain the conversation "Context" and I don't see a method or property of any of the related objects that would allow me to "reply with current context".
There is a number of posts floating around that use "GetChatCompletionsStreaming" but I have yet to see a example of replying to the completion of the first message a additional message in the same context.
If you want a good use case to get GPT-4 to hallucinate, ask it this exact question, it will provide you profoundly misleading and totally incorrect code. To be clear allot of this may be down to the "Azure.AI.OpenAI" version I am using, I'm currently using "1.0.0-beta.14" if that is not the optimal version please include that in your answer.
I have observed syntactically incompatible answers to various related questions, I would infer from that, that the API's are changing quite rapidly between releases and this is one of the reasons why GPT find's it so difficult to generate a reasonable and compatible answer.
How do I, in the version of the library referenced above, in C#, interact with a chatbot sending and receiving multiple messages in the same context.

I’ve not used this SDK per se but what you would want to do is make use of “Chat History” concept. You would add previous questions and answers to chat history and pass this chat history in the context.

@GauravMantri so yes, I've thought of that as a workaround, but that uses considerably more tokens, especially when your initial prompt is very large and your conversation has many reply's, you're basically paying for the entire conversation every-time you have a new reply, is that really the best way you can do that in the SDK? Sounds really expensive?

Basically yeah. Azure OpenAI (and everything like that) is essentially stateless and does not know what happened in the previous conversation unless you include that in the current conversation. Agreed, that it can get expensive (and you may end up exceeding the context window if you send too much data). To circumvent that one possibility would be to implement sliding chat history where you send last "x" questions/answers to LLM. Other option would be to constantly summarize the previous conversation and just send that summary instead of entire chat history.
